# Artifactory latestVersion search for groupId that includes "." (dot)

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

When searching for artifactory artifact using the latestVersion API, the g= (groupId) parameter specifies the layout where the artifact should be located. If the layout includes dots, then it's unclear how to escape the dots and consider them part of the object names.

This search fails since the layout is sensor/release-1.23/installers, but because dots are present in the object names, it's treated as the layout for the search API.

```
/artifactory/api/search/latestVersion?g=sensor.release-1.23.installers&a=sensor&repos=dev
```

Is there a workaround? escaping that can be used to specify that "release-1.23" should be treated as a single layout object and not split to "release-1", "23" ?

Comment: What escaping have you already tried? For example, `\".\"`, or `%2E`?

Comment: have you tried surrounding the layout object with single or double apostrophes?

Comment: Hi Roman Blachman, it would greatly help if you could post the `Layouts` of your repository. From what I have been able to dig around the `.` Should not be an issue.